# How to get secure access from AWS Lambda to Redis? Is VPC required?

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, redis, aws-lambda, amazon-elasticache

I need to cache some data in Redis and get access to it from AWS Lambda. 
How can I get secure access from AWS Lambda to Redis (AWS Elastic cache)?

Is VPC required? Because I know that VPC increase 1) AWS Lambdas cold starts 2) increase bills (network usage).

Comment: Where is the Redis server running? I see you tagged the question with `elastic-cache`, did you mean `amazon-elasticache`?

Comment: @MarkB, yes, amazon-elasticache, (updated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will need a VPC to connect to Redis.

AWS allows using lambda functions to connect to Elasticache.  Here is a link how it works - [Tutorial: Configuring a Lambda Function to Access Amazon ElastiCache in an Amazon VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-ec.html)

Also, I agree with VPC increasing cold starts, you can probably work around that by doing warmups and sharing context across Lambda invocations. More details can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html).

Comment: Thanks! So,  one more "architectural" question - if I create just one-two "util" lambdas that will be under VPC, and send requests to them, such as two middleware. is it enough good solution? Or setup any util server that will be middleware between redis and lambda?  I don't like idea to put 50 lambdas under VPC

Comment: I am assuming you mean that there will 2 Lambdas inside VPC which are calling Redis and all the other Lambdas will be outside VPC and they will access Redis through those 2 VPC Lambdas.


If your aim is to save run time, this approach will not help there. As you are still invoking the VPC lambda for each invocation so cold start time will still be the same.

Util server for Redis access does sound a better approach. You should try that.

Comment: got it... but one more question - if I have 2 VPC lambdas and 20+ lambdas out vpc that will send request to the VPC lambdas + warm-up - VPC lambdas must have "warmed" container most of time.. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, in theory, this looks feasible.